# Python code to read raw input until a button is pressed which is connected in gpio

Tags: gpio

I need a python program to read raw inputs until a button is pressed which is connted to GPIO pin 18.

below is the code.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import requests

names = []
string = ""
# Set new_name to something other than 'quit'.
new_name = ''

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
button_state = True
while button_state:

    input_state = GPIO.input(18)

    if input_state == False:
        button_state = False
        break
    if button_state == True:
        new_name = input("Enter Barcode :")
        names.append(new_name)
        string=string+new_name+','



# Add the list to cart.
tid = "TRANS8888777744445544"
key="CUST5164339121066924"

r = requests.post('http://ip:8080/myproject/'+key+'/'+tid+'/'+string,)
print (r.text)
```

Comment: How far have you got?  You need to show us your script and explain which parts are not working properly.  A photo of your connections will also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're wanting to look at input from two different things simultaneously, and one of your inputs (the call to `input` to read from the keyboard, or more likely the barcode reader acting as a keyboard) is a blocking function meaning it'll halt execution of your program until it gets a response.

So, walking through your code:

1. `button_state` starts off as True
2. The `while` loop tests `button_state`; it's True so we continue into the loop
3. We read the state of GPIO18. Let's assume it's True for now (i.e. the button isn't pushed, given the reversed logic of a pulled-up circuit)
4. The first `if` statement tests `input_state` but it's False so we skip down to the next `if` statement.
5. The second `if` statement tests `button_state`. That's True so we continue into the body of the `if` statement.
6. `input` is called which will halt the program until Enter is pushed.

Note that at this point you can push your button on GPIO18 as much as you like and the circuit will momentarily drop low for as long as you're holding the button, but it doesn't matter because you're not reading GPIO18 - the script is waiting on keyboard input (specifically until the Enter key is pressed). By the time you get back to reading GPIO18 you may not be pushing the button anymore.

What I suspect you want is to read two things *simultaneously* (or as near as possible that you don't notice the difference): the keyboard, and the GPIO18 pin. There's a couple of ways of going about this:

### Non-blocking keyboard input

Instead of using a blocking function like `input` that waits around for an entire string of characters until Enter is pressed, use non-blocking input which reads a character at a time (or nothing if no key is pressed) and returns immediately. That way you can go whizzing round your loop quickly and from a human's perspective it'll appear you're reading the two things more or less simultaneously. Unfortunately non-blocking input is non-trivial (you need to learn new ways to print , but here goes:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import curses
import time
import requests

names = []
string = ""

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def main(window):
    global names, string
    window.nodelay(True)
    new_name = ''
    while True:
        window.addstr(0, 0, 'Enter Barcode : %-30s' % new_name)
        window.refresh()
        if not GPIO.input(18):
            break
        try:
            key = window.getkey()
        except curses.error:
            # no key was pressed, give the CPU a breather :)
            time.sleep(0.001)
        else:
            if key == '\n':
                names.append(new_name)
                string = string + new_name + ','
                new_name = ''
            else:
                new_name += key


curses.wrapper(main)

# Add the list to cart.
tid = "TRANS8888777744445544"
key = "CUST5164339121066924"

r = requests.post('http://ip:8080/myproject/' + key + '/' + tid + '/' + string)
print (r.text)
```

### Threads

The alternative is to use threads to *really* do two things simultaneously. Conceptually this is a bit harder (you need to think about two control flows rather than a single linear one) but I think it's actually a lot simpler. I'll switch to GPIO Zero for this example just to keep things really easy:

```
import sys
import requests
from threading import Lock
from gpiozero import Button

# Set up a button on GPIO18 (GPIO Zero will handle the input state
# and pull-ups for us because we've told it there's a button attached)
btn = Button(18)
names = []
string = ""
globals_lock = Lock()

def add_to_cart():
    global names, string

    tid = "TRANS8888777744445544"
    key = "CUST5164339121066924"
    url = 'http://ip:8080/myproject/' + key + '/' + tid + '/' + string
    # reset the globals
    with globals_lock:
        names = []
    string = ""
    # POST the request
    r = requests.post(url)
    print(r.text)
    # Terminate the script - you probably want to get
    # rid of this eventually
    sys.exit(0)

# Set add_to_cart to run whenever the button attached
# to GPIO18 is pressed
btn.when_pressed = add_to_cart

# Now loop around getting barcodes
while True:
    new_name = input('Enter Barcode :')
    with globals_lock:
        names.append(new_name)
        string = string + new_name + ','
```

Comment: Thank you for the post Dave but the code dint work for me. Still the button press is not working.